# querty to convert OLD hash password to AES

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash, cryptography

i have a MySQL database who use old hash method.
Now i want to use this new hash method with AES

```
SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('%s', 'key'));
```

Soo, can someone help me with a query to convert all passwords maded with this hash

```
SELECT PASSWORD('TEST');
```

intro the new one ?

I think is not possible directly from  encrypted password to new one.. soo maybe
first decrypt(from old  ) query then encrypt(to new with aes) query.

Regards

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: No, no no.  He can't find the key.. because. key is stored intro c++ program.  The key is not stored intro mysql database, or intro php function. They key is intro compiled application.

Comment: @marc Doesn't change anything. If they get that application they get the key. There is no reason to use anything else than hashing for passwords.

Comment: @marc you put too much faith into the obfuscation of compiled binaries. A motivated (curiosity is often enough) attacker may find a lot of information by disassembling the compiled binary.

Comment: See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

Answer (score 2):

[Encryption and hashing are very different operations](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). Encryption is reversible. Hashing is one-way.

Furthermore, the [correct way to store passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016) doesn't involve fast hash functions like SHA1 (which MySQL uses for their `PASSWORD()` function), let alone AES, it involves a slow hashing function like bcrypt.

Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. Don't do it in a SQL query. Read [this section](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes) to learn how to migrate legacy hashes to a proper password storing algorithm.